# Free hand drawing on image in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-graphics, swiftui, ios13

I wanted to draw lines on the image. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60002068/12759144 link helps to draw on the shapes. I set gesture to image and tried drawing lines on the image. but it is not drawing the lines on the image.

Image(uiImage: self.shareImage).renderingMode(.original).resizable().padding(5).gesture(DragGesture().onChanged( { value in
                                    self.addNewPoint(value)

```
                            })
                                .onEnded( { value in
                                    self.isFirstTouchBegan = false
                                }))

                            DrawShape(pointss: points)
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 5) 
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
```

Attached screen for reference. [image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is fast implementation of drawing on `Rectangle`, but you can put any view you need. I used `Path` and saved every point at the `DragGesture` and than use these points to draw `Shape`:

```swift
struct DrawExample: View {

    @State var points: [CGPoint] = []

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Rectangle() // replace it with what you need
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged( { value in
                    self.addNewPoint(value)
                })
                .onEnded( { value in
                    // here you perform what you need at the end
                }))


            DrawShape(points: points)
                .stroke(lineWidth: 5) // here you put width of lines
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }

    }

    private func addNewPoint(_ value: DragGesture.Value) {
        // here you can make some calculations based on previous points
        points.append(value.location)
    }

}

struct DrawShape: Shape {

    var points: [CGPoint]

    // drawing is happening here
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        guard let firstPoint = points.first else { return path }

        path.move(to: firstPoint)
        for pointIndex in 1..<points.count {
            path.addLine(to: points[pointIndex])

        }
        return path
    }
}
```

with code above you can achieve this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to draw new shapes on every touch began. Looks like DragGesture doesn't have function related to touchbegan, Is there any function to know the touch began

Comment: Thank you! Provides a great starting point.

Comment: use touch.location in the .onChanged event, and use a state variable to remember if this is the first point you've seen.